# Test memory leak by instruments of Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, command-line, instruments

Can I use Xcode instruments to test memory leak of a C++ command line tool?

I tried to do so, and I cannot find a console to use `cin`.

However, for a iOS app, there will be a simulator so that we can do something to our program.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `iprofiler` tool ([manpage](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/iprofiler.1.html)) by adding this to the start of your command line:

```
iprofiler -leaks -d $HOME/tmp
```

(where `$HOME/tmp` is where you want the results written).

You can then open up the resulting `.dtps` bundle using *Instruments* to check for leaks (or any of the other 4 checks that `iprofiler` performs).

If you are using `clang` then compile with both `-O3` and `-g` (as `clang` doesn't support `-pg`).